# Passing data to ViewController which is content of UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Assuming that the project is using ARC.
ContentViewController is content of UIPopoverController

```
- (IBAction)showPop:(UIButton *)button 
{
    _pressDate = [NSDate date];
    ContentViewController *cvc = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:cvc];
    cvc.dateLabel.text = [_pressDate description];
    [self.popController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

The code above works, no problem. But I've noted that if I call

```
cvc.dateLabel.text = [_pressDate description];
```

before

```
self.popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:cvc];
```

the label does not get an update. I just would like to understand what is the matter?

Comment: I'm not sure of the sequence of events with a popover but the key point is that the ContentViewController's `viewDidLoad:` is the first place where its view hierarchy is guaranteed to exist.  You might try putting a log message there and another where you do the assignment to see what's happening.  (Or, log the value of `cvc.dateLabel` when you make the assignment.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's that my mistake is that those label in ContentViewController is an Outlet and declared as            @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel; and it was nil. But what is unclear for me is why it works if I assign text after initialization UIPopoverController

Comment: It will probably become clear if you put a log statement in `viewDidLoad:` and beside your assignment.  If your assignment is **after** `viewDidLoad:` it will work.

Comment: @Phillip Mills Now all the things are clear, thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thumbrule that you should not edit the UI of a ViewController before viewDidLoad is run, becuase of ther reasons `@Phillip Morris` described.. Instead of setting the `cvc.dateLabel.text` directly before viewDidLoad is fired, declare a property `textForDateLabel`, and set `cvc.textForDateLabel = [_pressDate description];`.
 Then in `viewDidLoad` of your ContentViewController, do `self.dateLabel.text = textForDateLabel;`

Comment: Thank you for extra info. I was too concentrated on those popover controller and ... it was stupid from my side.